# How to determine the basis of an endomorphism Jordan normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> $T$ is an endomorphism on $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ represented by the matrix $ A $:
> $$
> A = \begin{pmatrix}
> -1 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
> -1 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 &  1 &-1 & 1 \\
>  1 &  0 &-1 &-3 \\  
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

> The caracteristic polynomial is: $P_A(X) = (X + 2)^4$

> The minimal polynomial is: $M_A = (X + 2)^2$

> 1. Give a decomposition of $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ as a direct sum of cyclic subspaces of $T$, with their dimensions.

> 2. Give a Jordan normal form, with its basis.

---

1. Based on the minimal polynomial, the dimension of the cyclic subspaces will be 2, and we will have: $$ \mathbb{R}^4 = <e_1> \oplus <e_2> $$

with: $ <e_{1}> = vect\{ e_{1}, (T + 2I_d)(e_{1}) \} $ and $ <e_{2}> = vect\{ e_{2}, (T + 2I_d)(e_{2}) \} $

2. A jordan normal form of $ T $ would be:

$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 &-2 & 1 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &-2 \\  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The basis of $ J $ is the set of vectors:

$
\begin{cases}
v_1 = e_1 \\
v_2 = (T + 2I_d)(e_1) \\
v_3 = e_2 \\
v_4 = (T + 2I_d)(e_2)
\end{cases}
$

Are my answers correct?

Comment: I have shown what I tried. Why the downvote?

Comment: @calculatormathematical How is that helpful?

Comment: Your calculation of the jordan normal form is correct here - but you got a little lucky. Just from the fact that the minimal polynomial is $(X+2)^2$ we only know that the biggest jordan block is of size 2, but not that every Jordan block is of size 2. Without further calculation, another possible jordan normal form (based on the given facts) could have been $$\begin{pmatrix} -2&1&0&0\\0&-2&0&0\\0&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Lukas What about the basis? was it correct too?

Comment: And for the basis you have it in the wrong order. The first basis vector should be $(T+2I)e_1$ and the second one should be $e_1$. Because from the jordan normal form we see that the second basis vector is mapped to the first minus two times itself, so $T(e_1) = (T+2I)e_1 - 2I e_1$, but if you choose $e_1$ as the first vector this will not work.

Comment: @Lukas Thank you for your help sir.